# unable to add kendo grid add/remove/edit command directive in Angular 5

Tags: kendo-grid, angular5

I am trying to create kendo grid with angular 5 by following this example : https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/editing/external-editing/.
I have copied every file correctly, but still I am getting this error at kendoGridAddCommand / Edit / Remove

Error : AppMasterComponent.html:28 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'rtl' of null

```
at AddCommandDirective.ButtonDirective (button.directive.js:46)
at new AddCommandDirective (add-command.directive.js:28)
at createClass (core.js:12449)
at createDirectiveInstance (core.js:12284)
at createViewNodes (core.js:13742)
at createEmbeddedView (core.js:13619)
at callWithDebugContext (core.js:15056)
at Object.debugCreateEmbeddedView [as createEmbeddedView] (core.js:14368)
at TemplateRef_.createEmbeddedView (core.js:11694)
at ViewContainerRef_.createEmbeddedView (core.js:11406) 
AppMasterComponent.html:28 ERROR CONTEXT DebugContext_ {view: {…}, nodeIndex: 2, nodeDef: {…}, elDef: {…}, elView: {…}}
```

Kindly solve my problem.

Answer (score 3):

Your CommandDirective version is newer than require dependency package.
follow this https://npm.runkit.com/@progress/kendo-angular-buttons thus your package.json must look like this

```
"dependencies": {
.
.
.
"@angular/common": "^5.2.9",
"@angular/core": "^5.2.9",
"@progress/kendo-angular-l10n": "^1.1.0",
"rxjs": "^5.5.8",
"@progress/kendo-angular-buttons": "^4.0.0",
.
.
.
```

}

then delete node_modules folder in you project and reinstall npm install

***Edited***

> but I recommend you rollback
>   `@progress/kendo-angular-buttons": "^4.0.0" => "^3.0.4"` instead XD

Answer (score 1):

Great soultion. This is fix my issue,

@progress/kendo-angular-buttons": "^4.0.0" => "^3.0.4" instead

Answer (score 1):

In my case, uninstalling and installing back all the Kendo dependencies worked.

Answer (score -1):

I am using Angular 4 and getting same error
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'rtl' of null

---

Package.json
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.4.6",
    "@angular/common": "^4.3.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.3.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.3.0",
    "@angular/core": "^4.3.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.3.0",
    "@angular/http": "^4.3.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.3.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.3.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^4.3.0",
    "@angular/router": "^4.3.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-buttons": "^4.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-dateinputs": "^2.2.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-dropdowns": "^2.1.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-excel-export": "^1.0.7",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-grid": "^2.1.3",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-inputs": "^2.2.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-intl": "^1.3.2",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-l10n": "^1.1.0",
    "@progress/kendo-data-query": "^1.2.2",
    "@progress/kendo-drawing": "^1.5.1",
    "@progress/kendo-theme-default": "^2.49.1",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.8",
    "systemjs": "0.19.40",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.4"
  },

Comment: Update to "@progress/kendo-angular-grid": "3.2.0". This fixed it for me.